# Tag the parent stack from a CloudFormation template

Tags: templates, amazon-web-services, version-control, tagging, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to create tags on a CloudFormation stack from the template itself? (the parent stack, not nested stacks)

We have many templates, which get updated with each new version of software. Our software versions are tagged (in git), and it would be nice to see at a glance which version a particular stack was spooled up with.

The top-level [anatomy of a template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-anatomy.html) specifies 6 nested sections:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "version date",

  "Description" : "JSON string",

  "Metadata" : {
    template metadata
  },

  "Parameters" : {
    set of parameters
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    set of mappings
  },

  "Conditions" : {
    set of conditions
  },

  "Resources" : {
    set of resources
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    set of outputs
  }
}
```

But none of those sections seem to allow for the tagging of the stack itself (hopefully I am missing something here).

Yes, I could add a version string to the Metadata section, and that could be viewed by looking at the template for a particular stack, but tags are so much easier to work with in AWS. Plus it would allow much easier control over who can update/delete the stack.

At the moment we do not make much use of stack tags because of this limitation.

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

```
  create-stack
--stack-name <value>
...
[--tags <value>]
...
```

I think I've used that in the past to do about what you're talking about.  This allows me to search for stacks based on tags, just like almost every other thing in the AWS world.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted a solution that would define the tag within the template itself. You are correct that you can define tags manually when the stack is launched (or after is created), and unfortunately it seems this is the only option at present. Hopefully they will add the ability soon.

Comment: Yeah, I totally see what you're saying on that, and I completely agree.  How hard could it be to add a section for "Tags" along with "Resources" and everything else, right?  Specifying via the cli is just messy.  Although, one could make the argument that doing this through the api would be closer to what you're looking for.